# Iterating through Topojson external properties and storing totals over time

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

I have some JSON data I'm using with a projection of the US (state boundaries). I have loaded some external properties to each state such that each state has 12 months of data across four variables. Here is an example slice:

```
json_data['features'][1]['properties']

>>{state:'Alaska',
'JAN2016': {'x1':0, 'x2':0, 'x3':1, 'x4':0},
'FEB2016': {'x1':1, 'x2':0, 'x3':1, 'x4':0}, ... }
```

What I now want to do is calculate the national totals for each month to populate an array for each variable (i.e. `x1`, `x2`..) like so:

```
var x1NationalTotals = [24, 26, 29, ... ];
var x2NationalTotals = [30, 34, 32, ... ];
```

I just made those numbers up, but for clarity each item in the array would correspond to the national total for one year, and there would be four arrays -- one for each variable (`x1`, `x2` and so forth). Since I have 12 months worth of data, each array would have 12 items. I initially considered simply adding a new `Totals` feature to the JSON file itself, but in the long run my particular application will benefit from being able to do this post-parsing.

**Question:** I'm stuck at how to iterate through all 50 states. I'm thinking we might use a loop for this type of task, but I'm not sure how to loop across states *and* years and save totals. Or perhaps there is another approach besides a loop?

Comment: This kind of task is common in D3 data manipulations -- check out the docs for the function `d3.nest`, or walk-thru examples like https://amber.rbind.io/blog/2017/05/02/d3nest/

Comment: @SteveR that does look promising, thanks for pointing me in the right direction